# Help with physics simulation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, physics, game-physics

I'm studying simple physics for 2d games and I would like a help with a simulation I'm trying to do.

I have a bar that will fall over a fixed ball in the ground, xaml below:

```
<Canvas Background="CornflowerBlue">
    <Rectangle Name="bar" Width="200" Height="20" Fill="Cornsilk" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="50" />
    <Ellipse Name="ball" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="PaleGreen" Canvas.Left="380" Canvas.Top="250" />
</Canvas>
```

[image: Before bar starts falling]

I have all the calculations done to simulate the bar falling due to gravity but what I really need help with is, once the bar hits the ball, it's gonna have one side in the ground and the other side over the ball, which could be pretty much represented with the xaml:

```
<Canvas Background="CornflowerBlue">
    <Rectangle Name="bar" Width="200" Height="20" Fill="Cornsilk" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="246.675" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-18.897"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
    <Ellipse Name="ball" Height="50" Width="50" Fill="PaleGreen" Canvas.Left="380" Canvas.Top="250" />
</Canvas>
```

[image: Bar is on the ground]

And I don't know how to make the left side of the bar hit the ground while the left side will be over the ball in phisics terms.

I know there are awesome physics engine available like Farseen but I just want to understand how it would work in this case.

I know how to get the bar's Y based on time, so I keep checking it until it colides with the ball, but then what after that?

Thanks!

Comment: In order to do something like this, you're going to have to basically code your own 2D physics engine. The rectangle is going to have a 2D Box Collider attached to it, and the circle is going to have a Circle/Sphere collider. Every "tick" you need to check for collisions and apply forces as necessary. If you don't *need* to write this all yourself, I would **strongly** recommend that you find a physics engine you can use.

Comment: @SpikeX You should make this an answer +1

Comment: I didn't make it an answer because it doesn't answer his question, it was more a suggestion of "Don't reinvent the wheel." (as people often do).

Comment: thanks, but this is not reinventing the wheel, it's understanding how the wheel works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigid Body physical simulation is not a simple task Unless you are very interested in the topic I would recommend using a physics library. But if you are interested in doing this I would recommend looking at the [Physically Based Modeling](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/881/s99-course36.pdf) SIGGRAPH course notes, [Brian Mirtich's thesis](http://www.kuffner.org/james/software/dynamics/mirtich/index.html) on impulse based dynamics and perhaps also [Kenny Erleben's thesis](ftp://ftp.diku.dk/diku/image/publications/erleben.050401.pdf) on multibody dynamics.

These provide a very in depth description of how rigid body dynamics can be implemented.